Excel: How to sum columns m:n for rows x:y in a structured table
here is what my structured table looks like:
[Sample Table](https://i.sstatic.net/YjfsBt3x.png)
Table name = Sample
Purpose of Cell G1 value of 2 is to indicate "the 2 rows before the last row". If it were 3, it would be the 3 rows before the last row.
I am looking for a formula outside the table that will use the value of "2" in G1 to instruct the formula to --> Add Columns Quantity1 through Quantity2, but only for the "2 rows before the last row" in the "Sample" structured table.
The result should be 630 (200+300+60+70).
I can get most of the way there with this formula, but the COLUMN part is the issue... I'm trying to reference the column by title, but excel is taking the COLUMN value as a number (in this case, Quantity1 it sees as the 5th column in the workbook, but it's really only the 4th column in my Sample table since the table starts in Column B...) - not sure how to fix
=SUM(INDEX(Sample[#All],ROWS(Sample[#All])-1,COLUMN(Sample[[#Headers],[Quantity1]])):INDEX(Sample[#All],ROWS(Sample[#All])-1-$G$1,COLUMN(Sample[[#Headers],[Quantity2]])))

=SUM(CHOOSECOLS(DROP(TAKE(Sample,-G1-1),-1),4,5))
This makes use of the take, drop, choosecols, and sum functions.


=SUM(IFERROR(SIGN(XMATCH(Sample[Counter],-SEQUENCE(G1)))*Sample[[Quantity 1]:[Quantity 2]],0))
We can make use of the Counter column. If the negative sequence of the value in G1 matches the counter it returns the row number. Sign converts any positive (row) number to 1. Multiply it by the Qty1 & 2 values and count 0 for errors returns all values, which can be summed.
